# How can I stop that cakePHP 2.1 redirects all my new views?

Tags: php, cakephp, http-redirect

I hope you can forgive my bad english, I hate auto translating services... So I write by my own. xD

I am working in cakePHP 2.1, but the code is not mine. For some reason, when I create a new view with its correct controller created, the system redirectsme to the root. So, I cannot create a new view. Of course, the view exist in the controller becouse I add it.

For example, I add this code in `cake/Controller/DocumentsController.php`:

```
  function add_pago() {
     //I code for food.
  }
```

And I create a new file called `cake/Views/Documents/add_pago.ctp` with this random code after the php tag:

```
 echo "hello, world!";
```

There's no beforeFilter() function in DocumentsController.php. In AppController.php, the beforeFilter function is shown bellow:

```
 public function beforeFilter() {
    //Configure AuthComponent
    //$this->Auth->allow('display');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home');
    if(!empty($this->data)) array_walk_recursive($this->data, array($this, '__whitespace'));
}
```

Simple ACL is active. The programmer can't remeber what he did to get this behavior. And I can't figure how to fix this.

Do you have any suggestion to find where in the code is programmed this?

Comment: what is `cake` here ? you should have the proper folder structure if cake is the folder in your `www` then `cake/app/Controller/DocumentsController.php` is the correct path

Comment: I don't get your question, Anil :C

Comment: do you've the folder structure as like this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html#cakephp-folder-structure

Comment: I agree with @Anilkumar, it seems like you are creating your views and controllers in the wrong path, they should be created inside App directory

Comment: Lol, I spelled wrong in the post. Is the correct cake/app. However I found the error: It is ACL. Its preventing me to add new things. Thanks :D

Comment: why don't you use `$this->Auth->allow('add_pago');` in your `beforeFilter` callback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$this->Auth->allow('add_pago');` in your `beforeFilter` callback.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    //Configure AuthComponent
    //$this->Auth->allow('display');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home');
    if(!empty($this->data)) array_walk_recursive($this->data, array($this, '__whitespace'));
    $this->Auth->allow('add_pago');

    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Comment: I would not use allow() on a global beforeFilter() method (in AppController), though. Rather in that specific controller.

Comment: I said about the op's controller, so that it'll apply to only that action within that controller.